# API Database Picker

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, api

(Im trying my best to write everything right, but I normaly dont speak english)
So, I have a problem. I dont know how to do that things Below...

Topic: A player write his Player TAG (#XXXXXX) in my text box. After that he will recieve all the data from an external website/api (for example his LVL or XP)

(I put numbers on the picture i Linked so you can follow along (1.2.3 on the pictures))

[Picture Description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uuws9.jpg)

1. I have a Text input box (for a TAG "#XXXXXX") and a send button on my website. Thats all working.
2. Now i want, that the "TAG" (Which someone wrote in this box) to apear in my php exactly at the end of a link which will result a link to the API with all his information (look picture two)
3. This link will show all the information (Picture 3)
4. Now I want for example that the name gets displayed in my html (where my TAG input field is)

Can someone please tell me how to do that and maybe provide me with some code. Maybe with code, where it reads out the information of picture 3

Thank you guys
(Btw the user shouldnt see picture nr3 that should load in the background)

Comment: You want something that starts with `#XXXXXX` to be `exactly at the end of a link which will result a link` that can get a bit dicey because normally the [fragment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier) is not sent to the server.  Here is the short version `The fragment identifier (which starts with #) functions differently to the rest of the URI: its processing is exclusively client-side with no participation from the web server,`

Comment: I guess given the above, you should probably trim off that `#` or replace it before creating the url, it's a bad choice of identifiers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm operating on the assumption, based on NR2, that you're using some sort of MVC with a router, as you're definitely not using query-string params. I'm also assuming that your API is fully capable of doing the lookup since you've no provided any context on what that is.

That said, you should be able to simply construct the url as a string and call it in js/jquery.

```
    var theId
    var urlString = "myurl.com/test/api/"+theId;
    $.ajax({  
      url: urlString
    }).done(function(foo){
        console.log('bar',foo);
    });
```

The .done() function should be able to make any changes you need to do such as altering the .text() on the fields to reflect the data returned.

Some code from your actual project would be helpful, pictures can't be explored and there's no real context for what you're trying to bring about.